# Script, output from HTMLpurifier as plain text

Tags: php, html, xss, htmlpurifier

i try in short the HTMLpurifier library, after many input strings test i stack here, and i am wondering why this happened. Specifically, i have that function

```
 function filterxss($var){

 $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
 return $purifier->purify($var);
}
```

With that input string

```
$a = '<</script>script type="text/javascript">alert("test");<</script>/script>';
```

with that

```
echo filterxss($a);
```

it print this as plain text in browser. The echo produces that

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
```

Why the script wasnt executed ?

please dont vote negative. I ask for explanation

Comment: also you can try and tell us your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code of your purified elements is:

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;alert("test");&lt;/script&gt;
```

So it shows as pure text, not script